# Indentation in align* when using &=

Tags: math-mode, align, indentation

```
\begin{align*}
    \text{Assume for all i = 0, 1, ..., k, }\mathbb{P}(A_i\mid B) < \mathbb{P}(A_i)\\
    \text{Then, }\mathbb{P}(\Omega\mid B) &= \mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i\mid B)
\end{align*}
```

The first line is centered on the page which is great. However, the second line seems to be too much to the right of the page. When I replace '&=' with simply '=', the line is centered again. How can I make it centered while using '&=' to align with subsequent equations?

[image]

Comment: The `&` is used to align the lines with each other. Centered is the whole construct. At what point do you want the two lines to be aligned? Maybe a combination of `gather` and `aligned` is needed if there are more than these two lines.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three approaches that should work for the two-sentence system at hand. Not knowing anything about the mysterious "subsequent equations" mentioned by the OP, I can't tell if these approaches will work in a possibly very different setting.

- Continue to use an `align*` system, and place the `&` alignment markers at the start of each line.
- Switch to a `gather*` system and center both lines.
- Place only the second sentence in a display-math setting. That way, you concentrate visual attention on the result rather on both the assumption and the result. ("For if everything is special, then nothing is special.")

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\let\Pr\relax % un-define the existing '\Pr' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pr}{\mathbb{P}} % "probability operator"

\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block.
\begin{align*}
&\text{Assume for all $i = 0, 1, \dots, k,$ $\Pr(A_i\mid B) < \Pr(A_i)$.}\\
&\text{Then, }\Pr(\Omega\mid B) = \Pr\Bigl(\,\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i\mid B\Bigr)\,.
\end{align*}
\hrule
\begin{gather*}
\text{Assume for all $i = 0, 1, \dots, k,$ $\Pr(A_i\mid B) < \Pr(A_i)$.}\\
\text{Then, }\Pr(\Omega\mid B) = \Pr\Bigl(\,\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i\mid B\Bigr)\,.
\end{gather*}
\hrule
\bigskip\noindent
Assume for all $i = 0, 1, \dots, k,$ $\Pr(A_i\mid B) < \Pr(A_i)$. Then,
\[
\Pr(\Omega\mid B) = \Pr\Bigl(\,\bigcup_{i=1}^kA_i\mid B\Bigr)\,.
\]
\hrule
\end{document}
```